# How do I replace Icon with rectangle In ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the need to replace the Icon in a MenuItem with a Rectangle. Currently I have this:

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">                           
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>         
            </Style>         
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

Which works fine:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to edit the *MenuItem.Icon* and replace it with a rectangle.

I've tried using a DataTemplate:

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding CategoryColor}"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
     </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

And while this looks okay it would be nicer to get the Rectangle into the Icon area - or remove the icon area altogether. I also have to think about binding a Command to the MenuItem, if that makes a difference to the approach.

[image]

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:
I've tried:

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
        <ContextMenu.Resources>
            <Rectangle x:Key="myRectangle" x:Shared="False" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding CategoryColor}"/>
        </ContextMenu.Resources>
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>  
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource myRectangle}"/>
            </Style>         
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

But this only displays the last rectangle:

[image]

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into my test app and I can't duplicate this behaviour. Quick sanity check: have you populated the color in the bound objects?

Comment: Yes I have - the second code example above uses the exact same ItemsSource.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of options. My test app has a single ObservableCollection<MyThing> called Categories. MyThing has a string property Name and a string property CategoryColor. I populated Categories with 4 MyThings: {"Testing", "Red"} / {"Testing2", "Blue"} / {"Testing3", "Orange"} / {"Testing4", "Yellow"} . All firing as expected.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm using a Brush rather than a String property. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Aha! It's for the same reason that you need x:Shared on the Rectangle. It'll try and reuse the Brush if that's not set, meaning that every subsequent user of it 'steals' it. Unfortunately there is, as far as I can Google, no means of setting that programmatically: 'There is no direct code equivalent for x:Shared in the WPF object model; it can only be specified in a XAML usage' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) .

Comment: @goobering, I was using `Brush`, and your answer is working perfectly.

Comment: @Bolu Mysterious. I tried it with Brush and hit the x:Shared issue. How did you instantiate/set your Brush?

Comment: @goobering, define property `CategoryColor` as `System.Windows.Media.Brush` and set it as `System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red` for example: `Categories.Add(new Category() { Name = "Admin", CategoryColor = Brushes.Red });`  And the XAML is the same that OP has used.

Comment: and here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/Rvo7wVl.png

Comment: Argh. I've just retested mine with Brushes and SolidColorBrushes and it's all working perfectly. Buggered if I know what I did to make it fall over the first time.

Comment: I suspect mine isn't working because the ContextMenu (and it's resources) are sitting in in a ControlTemplate for a custom control. As detailed above and here: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx] **x:Shared** doesn't seem to work in a nested ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to deal with similar situation, and after trying to override default style and do all the styling again.. I realised having a -ve margin on your rectangle would be the easiest way out..

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-20,0,0,0">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding CategoryColor}"/>
         <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and effective.

Comment: yea, it should have been neater and easier to override template of just the icon, but it is how it is right now ! glad it helped !

Answer (score 2):

A second option is to define a Rectangle in your ResourceDictionary with x:Shared set to False:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Rectangle x:Key="myRectangle" x:Shared="False" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding CategoryColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

...and then use that in your Style:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource myRectangle}" />
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried this by putting the rectangle in *ContextMenu.Resources* but it only seems to bind the color to the last entry. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: I didn't try that! I do know that the x:Shared flag is crucial when putting it in the ResourceDictionary, as otherwise the resource is stolen by any successive elements that make use of it, leading to exactly what you describe.

Comment: Hmm. I've just tested this, and it seems to behave itself on my test app when added to ContextMenu.Resources. Did you set x:Shared?

Comment: Yes I did - I've added the code in the answer - and the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the rectangle to be in the icon Property and not just a negative margin I found it to work well to just put a rectangle in the content of the menu item icon:

```
 <MenuItem Header="Yellow">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
       <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
 </MenuItem>
```